# Converting a image to 32bpp format gives strange offset?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I have the following code:

```
       public static Bitmap ConvertTo32bppArgb(this Image image)
    {
        Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp))
        {
            gfx.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }

        return newBmp;
    }
```

However with some images this is giving some weird 1 pixel offset in that starts somewhere in the middle of the image. This happens with Format32bppArgb format but not with Format8bppIndexed.

What i want is that this function always returns a Bitmap that has Format32bppArgb (without that strange offset ofcourse).

Original image:

[image]

Processed image (see the tile 7th tile from the top (starts at pixel coordinates 0, 192) its 32x33 instead of 32x32)):

[image]

Comment: For those interested this is the image which iam getting the strange offset: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AleP4StyYmiAm8YPx9I-sN2yCCsjAw

Comment: You can edit your post and put the image in there instead of in a comment. I'm looking at the image and don't see the "strange offset" you are talking about. Where is it? What are we looking for? You mean a physical offset, as if half of the image is one pixel over and there's now a 1 pixel black stripe down the center or something?

Comment: @Quantic That was the original image. I have edited my post to include both original and converted image

Comment: The actual duplicate row of pixels is located at Y = 222. From there on all pixels have shifted one pixel to the bottom which means the tiles at the bottom now have 1 pixel less

Comment: Can you try to omitt the unnecessary scaling options and also use DrawImageUnscaled

Comment: "This happens with Format32bppArgb format but not with Format8bppIndexed" -- How did you do that? According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx), you should get an exception: "If the image has an indexed pixel format, this method throws an exception ... The indexed pixel formats are shown in the following list:  ... Format8bppIndexed".

Comment: Is 'this' a typo: `public static Bitmap ConvertTo32bppArgb(this Image image)` ?

Comment: @TaW probably it is an extension method.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks :-)

Comment: This is caused by your PixelOffsetMode selection.   HighQuality is useful when you *actually* need to interpolate the image.  You don't, you want a straight copy from the source image without interpolation and you properly selected NearestNeighbor.  With the current setting you see the side-effect of round-off error caused by GDI+ internally using floating point math.  Use PixelOffsetMode.Half instead.  (or was it None, I forget.  You'll see).

Comment: Thanks for your answers I will try them out later